# How to convert array of object into expected json key value object based on the path value

Tags: json, path, jq

This is my sample input
Input

```json
[
  {
    "label": "test1",
    "value": 1,
    "path": "data/testData/testDataLevel3/testDataLevel3_1/0/testDataLevel3_1_a2"
  },
  {
    "label": "test2",
    "value": 2,
    "path": "data/testData/testDataLevel1/testDataLevel1_1"
  }
]
```

This input needs to be converted like this using jq

Expected output:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "testData": {
      "testDataLevel1": { //object
        "testDataLevel1_1": 2
      },
      "testDataLevel3": {
        "testDataLevel3_1": [ //array
          {
            "testDataLevel3_1_a2": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The path will contain the array index as path, and sometimes the keys will be combined in the path as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert each `.path` to a form [`setpath`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#setpath(PATHS;VALUE)) can understand. The rest is straightforward.

```
reduce .[] as {$path, $value} (null;
  setpath($path / "/" | map(tonumber? // .); $value)
)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/lhJF0tenpE)</sup>